# How to cluster list-of-list by distance condition in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have the following list of lists that contains 6 entries:

```
lol = [['a', 3, 1.01],
       ['x', 5, 1.00],
       ['k', 7, 2.02],
       ['p', 8, 3.00],
       ['b', 10, 1.09], 
       ['f', 12, 2.03]]
```

Each sublist  in `lol` contains 3 elements:

```
['a', 3, 1.01]
  e1  e2  e3
```

The list above is already sorted according to `e2` (i.e, 2nd element)

I'd like to 'cluster' the above list following roughly these steps:

1. Pick the lowest entry (wrt. e2) in `lol` as the key of first cluster
2. Assign that as first member of the cluster (dictionary of list)
3. Calculate the difference current e3 in next list with first member 
     of existing clusters.
4. If the difference is less than threshold, assign that list as
      the member of the corresponding cluster
     Else, create new cluster with current list as new key.
5. Repeat the rest until finish

The final result will look like this, with threshold <= 0.1.

```
dol = {'a':['a', 'x', 'b'],
       'k':['k', 'f'],
       'p':['p']}
```

I'm stuck with this, what's the right way to do it:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

thres = 0.1
tmp_e3 = 0
tmp_e1 = "-"

lol = [['a', 3, 1.01], ['x', 5, 1.00], ['k', 7, 2.02],
       ['p', 8, 3.00], ['b', 10, 1.09], ['f', 12, 2.03]]

dol = defaultdict(list)
for thelist in lol:
    e1, e2, e3 = thelist

    if tmp_e1 == "-":
        tmp_e1 = e1
    else:
        diff = abs(tmp_e3 - e3)
        if diff > thres:
            tmp_e1 = e1

    dol[tmp_e1].append(e1)
    tmp_e1 = e1
    tmp_e3 = e3

print json.dumps(dol, indent=4)
```

Comment: What's `print json.dumps(dol, indent=4)` giving you?

Comment: @Yax: `{'a': ['a', 'x'], 'b': ['b'], 'f': ['f'], 'k': ['k'], 'p': ['p']}`

Comment: Sorry I went out to pray. You will think this through the execution of your code. Now, include `print diff > thress, thelist` in your `else` statement to see the hint it gives.

Comment: Remember the first list will also meet your condition which will now make it 5.

Comment: OT: I recommend `pprint.pprint(data)` instead of `print json.dumps(data)`

Comment: I think I must misunderstand your problem statement, why is data sorted according to `e2`? This column doesn't seems to be used anywhere... in a naive solution, I'd get `ax|k|p|b|f`, then if I were to re-sort the list, clusters are `xab|kf|p`, only the order of elements in a cluster is different. The question is, why not cluster by `e3` first and then pick cluster leader according to `e2`? (caveat: different results in corner cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first ensure lol is sorted on second element, then iterate keeping in the list only what in not in threshold from first element :

```
import json

thres = 0.1
tmp_e3 = 0
tmp_e1 = "-"

lol = [['a', 3, 1.01], ['x',5, 1.00],['k',7, 2.02],
       ['p',8, 3.00], ['b', 10, 1.09], ['f', 12, 2.03]]

# ensure lol is sorted
lol.sort(key = (lambda x: x[1]))
dol = {}

while len(lol) > 0:
    x = lol.pop(0)
    lol2 = []
    dol[x[0]] = [ x[0] ]
    for i in lol:
        if abs(i[2] - x[2]) < thres:
            dol[x[0]].append(i[0])
        else:
            lol2.append(i)
    lol = lol2

print json.dumps(dol, indent=4)
```

Result :

```
{
    "a": [
        "a", 
        "x", 
        "b"
    ], 
    "p": [
        "p"
    ], 
    "k": [
        "k", 
        "f"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Letting e2/e3 aside, here's a rough draft.

First generator groups data by value, it does need data to be sorted by value though.

Then an example use, first raw and then with data re-sorted by value.

```
In [32]: def cluster(lol, threshold=0.1):
    cl, start = None, None
    for e1, e2, e3 in lol:
        if cl and abs(start - e3) <= threshold:
            cl.append(e1)
        else:
            if cl: yield cl
            cl = [e1]
            start = e3
             if cl: yield cl

In [33]: list(cluster(lol))
Out[33]: [['a', 'x'], ['k'], ['p'], ['b'], ['f']]

In [34]: list(cluster(sorted(lol, key = lambda ar:ar[-1])))
Out[34]: [['x', 'a', 'b'], ['k', 'f'], ['p']]
```